# Teradata SQL - change timestamp to date

Tags: sql-server, teradata

I have a table with two columns:

```
Column1: Email_address[VARCHAR(255), UNICODE]
Column2: newsletter_subscription_date [TIMESTAMP (0)] e.g. DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

Goal: I want to write a query that tells me how many subscriptions were made on a daily basis in a specific timeframe.

Problem: I don't know how to convert the timeframe into a date format YYYY/MM/DD

The query I have so far:

```
SELECT  CAST(newsletter_subscription_date AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY/MM/DD'), COUNT(*)
FROM emailtable WHERE newsletter_subscription_date >= DATE - 30
GROUP BY newsletter_subscription_date
ORDER BY newsletter_subscription_date DESC
```

But all I get is something like this:

```
 newsletter_subscription_date   Count(*)
1   18.01.2017  1
2   18.01.2017  1
3   18.01.2017  1
4   18.01.2017  1
5   18.01.2017  1
6   18.01.2017  1
7   18.01.2017  1
8   18.01.2017  1
9   18.01.2017  1
10  18.01.2017  1
11  18.01.2017  1
```

How can I transform the timestamp to a proper date?

Comment: It's already a proper date after the CAST, but your client (SQL Assistant?) formats it using local rules based on Windows settings. In SQL Assistant you can change the format in *Tools > Options > Data Format > Display dates in this format".

Comment: Doesn't change the outcome, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, now I see, you group by the original timestamp column. You need to either `GROUP BY CAST(newsletter_subscription_date AS DATE)` or `GROUP BY 1`

Answer (score 1):

Try giving your re-cast column a new name and group by that instead:

```
SELECT  CAST(newsletter_subscription_date AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY/MM/DD') as sub_date, 
        COUNT(*) as num_subscriptions
FROM    emailtable 
WHERE   newsletter_subscription_date >= DATE - 30
GROUP BY sub_date
ORDER BY sub_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cast the date to a char and format that as you like before presenting it

```
sel to_char(CAST(newsletter_subscription_date AS date),  'YYYY/MM/DD'),  COUNT(*)
FROM emailtable WHERE newsletter_subscription_date >= DATE - 30
GROUP BY newsletter_subscription_date
ORDER BY newsletter_subscription_date DESC
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change the outcome :( It still lists the same date multiple times.